# Conditional Probability with four variables

Tags: conditional-probability, density-function, bayes-theorem, artificial-intelligence

In the book A First Course in Machine Learning, second edition, by Simon Rogers, page 322, the author states that the joint posterior density over f and y is given by:

p(f, y | t, X) = p(t|y) * p(y|f) * p(f|X) / p(t|X)

I have tried many times to get to that result using condition probability and Bayes´ rule, but to no avail. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Since the LHS is joint posterior density, your $p(t|y)$ is a short description to $p(T=t|Y=y)$, where both $T$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables evaluated at value $t$ and $y$, respectively, and $p$ is a probability density function to which Bayes theorem still applies [in the usual form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Statement_of_theorem). Thus from LHS we can have below where the second equality is due to conditional density function.
$$
\begin{aligned}
p(f, y|t, X) &= p(t | f, y, X)p(f,y|X) / p(t|X) \\
&= p(t|f, y, X)p(y|f)p(f|X) / p(t|X) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus to arrive at your book's conclusion it must somewhere indicates that the random variable T only depends on random variable Y and not $F$ or background $X$, so that you can have $p(t|y)=p(t|f, y, X)$ to arrive at your claimed goal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in case T only depends on Y, does the denominator p(t|X) make any sense?

Comment: Absolutely yes, the denominator which is called evidence in my reference is necessary per my first equality since this is required from applying correct (consistent) Bayesian inference. Notice F depends on background $X$ thus $T$ is *implicitly* and ultimately dependent on $X$ marginally, however, once $F$ is realized/evaluated at value $f$, $T$ is no longer needed to be conditioned on $X$ *explicitly*, though in denominator here without the conditioning of rv $F$, $T$ needs to be conditioned on $X$ in a marginal fashion in the absence of any nuance parameter such as $F$.